# Ruby: shorter way to define instance variables

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

I'm looking for the shorter way to define instance variables inside the `initialize` method:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar, :baz, :qux
  # Typing same stuff all the time is boring
  def initialize(foo, bar, baz, qux)
    @foo, @bar, @baz, @qux = foo, bar, baz, qux
  end
end
```

Does Ruby have any in-build feature which lets to avoid this kind of monkey job?

```
# e. g.
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar, :baz, :qux
  # Typing same stuff all the time is boring
  def initialize(foo, bar, baz, qux)
    # Leveraging built-in language feature
    # instance variables are defined automatically
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meet [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Struct.html), a tool made just for this!

```
MyClass = Struct.new(:foo, :bar, :baz, :qux) do
  # Define your other methods here. 
  # Initializer/accessors will be generated for you.
end

mc = MyClass.new(1)
mc.foo # => 1
mc.bar # => nil
```

I often see people use Struct like this:

```
class MyStruct < Struct.new(:foo, :bar, :baz, :qux)
end
```

But this results in one additional unused class object. Why create garbage when you don't need to?

Comment: What is the advantage of defining class with this way?

Comment: I mean the way that you are using in your answer.

Comment: There are two ways in my answer.

Comment: First way in your answer.

Comment: @GaneshKunwar: how about reading the linked docs? And the rest of the answer?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, what if I don't need attr readers, but just need instance vars to bee defined?

Comment: @DreamWalker: but you do need the accessors, as shown in your snippets in the question. If, in another case, you don't, then you could employ a meta-programming trick, similar to one in Lukas' answer. In my experience, if you have an ivar, you need at least the reader for it. Working with naked ivars is bad practice.

Comment: Your answer would be better *without* the subclass example :-)

Comment: @Stefan: it's a common mis-usage, so I thought I'd warn not to do it :)